# Cannot move cursor to absolute left of screen

Tags: mouse, cursor

My mouse cursor refuses to go to the absolute left of the screen, instead visually it stops a couple of pixels before the edge and then just doesn't go anywhere until I drag my mouse to the right again.
"Physically" the pointer does still move, because I see tooltips popping up when I move my mouse up and down in this visual "dead zone", but the pointer itself is stuck.

I saw this exact same problem in KDE Neon, now I'm running Ubuntu 17.04.
So the problem seems to exist on somewhat of a deeper level. 
Linux Mint and Elementary OS don't seem affected by this issue but they are based on older Ubuntu builds then KDE Neon and Ubuntu 17.04.

I tried googling for this, but I can't find anything apart from stuff that  is vaguely related like disappearing cursors.

Playing with things like scaling en resolution does not seem to affect this in any way.

I'm on an intel NUC NUC55PPYH.